# These stars, of more than a few solar masses, evolve, in general, much more rapidly than does a star like the Sun

Tags: meaning-in-context

Below is a paragraph from the GRE test:

"Upwards of a billion stars in our galaxy have burnt up their internal energy sources, and so can no longer produce the heat a star needs to oppose the inward force of gravity. These stars, of more than a few solar masses, evolve, in general, much more rapidly than does a star like the Sun. Moreover, it is just these more massive stars whose collapse does not halt at intermediate stages (that is, as white dwarfs or neutron stars). Instead, the collapse continues until a singularity (an infinitely dense concentration of matter) is reached. "

Does this sentence "These stars, of more than a few solar masses, evolve, in general, much more rapidly than does a star like the Sun." suggest a comparison between these stars' mass and the Sun's mass? From my gut feeling it seems so but I cannot find such a comparison based on its grammar devices or sentence structure.

All I can tell is that these stars are more than a few solar masses, the fact of which correlates a faster evolution rate of these stars. Nothing else could I get from the sentence otherwise I feel any further inference might be a far stretch.

Could anyone share your thoughts? Thanks a lot!

---

[Editing Note]: I further specify the question to narrow it down to asking whether a comparison between these stars' mass and the Sun's mass. I can tell a comparison between the stars and the Sun, but not a specific one between their masses. Your thoughts would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, but only indirectly.  The Sun is very like the Sun.

Comment: Stripping some distracting elements (particularly, a load of totally unnecessary commas), gives *These stars evolve more rapidly than **a star like the Sun***. Which is still just an unnecessarily verbose alternative to ***These stars evolve more rapidly than the Sun***.

Comment: Answers in comments guys, when there are **already proper answers.** Rude.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying sentence is "These stars ... evolve much more rapidly than [a star like our sun] does".

Where a short verb follows a long complement, it is common (particularly in formal or academic writing) to [extrapose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition) the long complement phrase (in brackets above), giving

> These stars evolve much more rapidly than does [a star like our sun].

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Sun is being compared, but *indirectly*.

Consider:

> An athlete like Lionel Messi is rare.

The phrase "like Lionel Messi" applies Messi's qualities to the abstraction "an athlete".  **An athlete with Messi's qualities is rare.** Messi is such an athlete, or course, as Messi has his qualities.

> These stars, of more than a few solar masses, evolve, in general, much more rapidly than does a star like the Sun.

These stars ... evolve ... much more rapidly than does **a star like the Sun**.

The Sun's qualities are applied to the abstraction "a star".

A star with the Sun's qualities (which would include the Sun) evolves more slowly than those collapsing stars.

That last sentence of mine is somewhat colloquial in that **evolve** is understood to be there:

> ... evolves more slowly than those collapsing stars [evolve].

But some editors would ignore the fact that **evolve** is virtually  there, and complain that evolution of a star cannot be compared to a star, and they might prefer the more formal:

> ... evolves more slowly than **do** those collapsing stars.

since there, action is compared to action.

And that could be rewritten to be less wooden, to reflect how people speak naturally:

> ... evolves more slowly than those collapsing stars **do**.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes.
You could paraphrase it very approximately as

> These large stars evolve more rapidly than our own Sun.

The original is somewhat tortuous, but clear in meaning.
The inference being that the larger mass contributes to a faster collapse, due to the increased gravitational effect. This is something I remember from high-school physics. I can't remember whether the larger mass also directly contributes to a faster burn-out, but one could infer that also.

Or, very colloquially - 'the bigger they are the harder they fall' ;)